# Inbound calc fields do not reference outgoing app

Tags: php, api, podio

When trying to parse a calc field to determine the source of the incoming relationship, I realized that the calc field only returns 1) the relationship field_id which is connecting the two apps and 2) the field_id in which the data is being pulled from. Example here:

“(in_sum_153102047_153102037)“

As this doesn't provide the app_id, this causes issues as there is no cohesive way to find the app in which the field is in. This is the case as the "Get App Field" call requires an app_id parameter. If this is true, the only way to find the app in which these fields are contained is to run app-by-app on the org until you happen to run into the field_id in question. As this is both API and time intensive, I'm hoping there is a better way.

Please advise.

"Thank you"

Nate

Answer (score 0):

An easiest way(but not a final solution) is,

You will get the app or set of apps which are connected to the reference field.
Try iterating them to find where the field coming from.
Hope it helps.

Comment: That's pretty much where I understand the current "best way" to be, but that ends up requiring a LOT of API calls as I have to run a Get App References then run a Get App by ID for each of the apps. For the app/field in question, this is no less than 40 total references.